# Batch file set line of text file as single variable in loop

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file to run through a list of domains and then use each on as a variable and then run a reg export on these like below:-

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (domains.txt) do set Domain=%%x
GOTO :ExportReg 

:ExportReg
reg export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ipswitch\IMail\Domains\%Domain% C:\export-%Domain%.txt
echo %%Domain%%

:End
```

but this just tries to output it all to the same file, causing overwrite errors

so it outputs as c:\export-domain.com.txt then the next one is say domain.co.uk but it tries to write it to domain.com.txt again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initial code will only every process the last domain in your domains.txt file. I would think you would want to process all domains.  Would be much easier to do everything within the FOR command.

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (domains.txt) do (
    reg export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ipswitch\IMail\Domains\%%x C:\export-%%x.txt
)
```